# What happens if 1 person misses the outbound flight on a return ticket where there are multiple people on the same reservation?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, family, missed-flights

I have bought return tickets for myself and 3 other family members. I have only one reservation number for the 4 of us.

What happens if for instance one of us misses the outbound flight (no show)? The other 3 will fly normally.

Will they cancel the inbound flight for everyone or just the person that missed the flight?

Comment: Just the person who missed the flight.

Comment: Avianca, does it vary by airline?

Answer (score 3):

There is a recent discussion about (roughly) this on [FlyerTalk](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/avianca-lifemiles-amigo/1743892-how-cancel-one-passenger-s-travel-joint-pnr.html) - happily also Avianca, from which I conclude your would-be fellow passengers need not fear your depriving them of their seats.

> When you try to cancel tickets they are actually processed one at a time (you pay $50 per ticket) ... It should be absolutely not problem to cancel just one of the two tickets. Just call the Avianca call-center and say you wish to cancel a reservation, then explain you wish to cancel only one out of the two passengers.

*(scibuff Feb 3, 16, 6:28 pm)*

It may be worth contacting Avianca, with a good reason, to see if your return flight could be held for you regardless of a fairly standard sector convention that failing to show up for any one of a series of flights booked as a series will give rise to cancellation of all the remainder of the series.

That is, if you are considering flying out a little later than presently booked but would like to return according to your original schedule.